# $.getJSON for loop on local

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps, markers

I am trying to read the JSON file that is stored in the same directory with this code. I need to retrieve the GPS information and use it to plot markers on the map. However, nothing appear after running the code. This is my JSON file.

```
[{
  "SourceFile": "C:/Users/wolvix/Downloads/sample image/1024-2006_1011_093752.jpg",
  "ExifToolVersion": 9.65,
  "FileName": "1024-2006_1011_093752.jpg",
  "Directory": "C:/Users/wolvix/Downloads/sample image",
  "FileSize": "205 kB",
  "FileModifyDate": "2014:06:29 18:42:21+08:00",
  "FileAccessDate": "2014:06:29 18:42:20+08:00",
  "FileCreateDate": "2014:06:29 18:42:21+08:00",
  "FilePermissions": "rw-rw-rw-",
  "FileType": "JPEG",
  "MIMEType": "image/jpeg",
  "JFIFVersion": 1.01,
  "ExifByteOrder": "Little-endian (Intel, II)",
  "ImageDescription": "KONICA MINOLTA DIGITAL CAMERA",
  "Make": "Konica Minolta Camera, Inc.",
  "Model": "DiMAGE A2",
  "Orientation": "Horizontal (normal)",
  "ModifyDate": "2006:10:11 09:37:52",
  "ExifVersion": "0221",
  "DateTimeOriginal": "2006:10:11 09:37:52",
  "CreateDate": "2006:10:11 09:37:52",
  "GPSVersionID": "0.0.2.2",
  "GPSLatitudeRef": "South",
  "GPSLongitudeRef": "East",
  "GPSAltitudeRef": "Above Sea Level",
  "Compression": "JPEG (old-style)",
  "Keywords": "Australia",
  "By-line": "John Harmon",
  "Province-State": "New South Wales",
  "Country-PrimaryLocationCode": "AUS",
  "Country-PrimaryLocationName": "Australia",
  "Caption-Abstract": "Sydney Harbor from the Manly-Sydney ferry",
  "URL": "",
  "ImageWidth": 1024,
  "ImageHeight": 768,
  "GPSAltitude": "0 m Above Sea Level",
  "GPSLatitude": "33 deg 51' 21.91\" S",
  "GPSLongitude": "151 deg 13' 11.73\" E",
  "GPSPosition": "33 deg 51' 21.91\" S, 151 deg 13' 11.73\" E",
  "ImageSize": "1024x768"
},
{
  "SourceFile": "C:/Users/wolvix/Downloads/sample image/12382975864_09e6e069e7_o.jpg",
  "ExifToolVersion": 9.65,
  "FileName": "12382975864_09e6e069e7_o.jpg",
  "Directory": "C:/Users/wolvix/Downloads/sample image",
  "FileSize": "6.0 MB",
  "FileModifyDate": "2014:07:17 18:37:24+08:00",
  "FileAccessDate": "2014:07:17 18:37:19+08:00",
  "FileCreateDate": "2014:07:17 18:37:19+08:00",
  "FilePermissions": "rw-rw-rw-",
  "FileType": "JPEG",
  "MIMEType": "image/jpeg",
  "ExifByteOrder": "Little-endian (Intel, II)",
  "ImageDescription": "OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA         ",
  "Make": "OLYMPUS IMAGING CORP.",
  "Model": "STYLUS1",
  "Orientation": "Horizontal (normal)",
  "ModifyDate": "2014:01:23 14:57:18",
  "ExifVersion": "0230",
  "DateTimeOriginal": "2014:01:23 14:57:18",
  "CreateDate": "2014:01:23 14:57:18",
  "GPSVersionID": "2.3.0.0",
  "GPSLatitudeRef": "North",
  "GPSLongitudeRef": "West",
  "GPSAltitudeRef": "Above Sea Level",
  "GPSStatus": "Measurement Active",
  "PrintIMVersion": "0300",
  "Compression": "JPEG (old-style)",
  "GPSAltitude": "0 m Above Sea Level",
  "GPSLatitude": "50 deg 49' 8.59\" N",
  "GPSLongitude": "0 deg 8' 12.45\" W",
  "GPSPosition": "50 deg 49' 8.59\" N, 0 deg 8' 12.45\" W",
  "ImageSize": "3968x2976"
},
{
  "SourceFile": "C:/Users/wolvix/Downloads/sample image/gg_gps.jpg",
  "ExifToolVersion": 9.65,
  "FileName": "gg_gps.jpg",
  "Directory": "C:/Users/wolvix/Downloads/sample image",
  "FileSize": "79 kB",
  "FileModifyDate": "2014:07:17 18:36:00+08:00",
  "FileAccessDate": "2014:07:17 18:35:58+08:00",
  "FileCreateDate": "2014:07:17 18:36:00+08:00",
  "FilePermissions": "rw-rw-rw-",
  "FileType": "JPEG",
  "MIMEType": "image/jpeg",
  "JFIFVersion": 1.02,
  "ExifByteOrder": "Little-endian (Intel, II)",
  "Make": "NIKON CORPORATION",
  "Model": "NIKON D2H",
  "Orientation": "Horizontal (normal)",
  "ModifyDate": "2005:07:02 10:38:28",
  "ExifVersion": "0220",
  "DateTimeOriginal": "2003:11:23 18:07:37",
  "CreateDate": "2003:11:23 18:07:37",
  "GPSVersionID": "2.2.0.0",
  "GPSLatitudeRef": "North",
  "GPSLongitudeRef": "East",
  "GPSTimeStamp": "18:07:37",
  "GPSDateStamp": "2003:11:23",
  "Compression": "JPEG (old-style)",
  "GPSDateTime": "2003:11:23 18:07:37Z",
  "GPSLatitude": "39 deg 54' 56.00\" N",
  "GPSLongitude": "116 deg 23' 27.00\" E",
  "GPSPosition": "39 deg 54' 56.00\" N, 116 deg 23' 27.00\" E",
  "ImageSize": "500x375"
},
{
  "SourceFile": "C:/Users/wolvix/Downloads/sample image/s_gps.jpg",
  "ExifToolVersion": 9.65,
  "FileName": "s_gps.jpg",
  "Directory": "C:/Users/wolvix/Downloads/sample image",
  "FileSize": "44 kB",
  "FileModifyDate": "2014:07:17 18:36:45+08:00",
  "FileAccessDate": "2014:07:17 18:36:44+08:00",
  "FileCreateDate": "2014:07:17 18:36:45+08:00",
  "FilePermissions": "rw-rw-rw-",
  "FileType": "JPEG",
  "MIMEType": "image/jpeg",
  "JFIFVersion": 1.02,
  "ExifByteOrder": "Little-endian (Intel, II)",
  "ImageDescription": "Communications",
  "Make": "FUJIFILM",
  "Model": "FinePixS1Pro",
  "Orientation": "Horizontal (normal)",
  "ModifyDate": "2002:07:19 13:28:10",
  "ExifVersion": "0200",
  "DateTimeOriginal": "2002:07:13 15:58:28",
  "CreateDate": "2002:07:13 15:58:28",
  "GPSVersionID": "2.0.0.0",
  "GPSLatitudeRef": "North",
  "GPSLongitudeRef": "West",
  "GPSTimeStamp": "14:58:24",
  "GPSMapDatum": "WGS84",
  "Compression": "JPEG (old-style)",
  "Province-State": " ",
  "Country-PrimaryLocationName": "Ubited Kingdom",
  "Keywords": "Communications",
  "CopyrightNotice": "ian Britton - FreeFoto.com",
  "IPTCDigest": "f58a446d60cbb1883f4201ed4420ac36",
  "DisplayedUnitsX": "inches",
  "DisplayedUnitsY": "inches",
  "GlobalAngle": 30,
  "GlobalAltitude": 30,
  "City": " ",
  "State": " ",
  "Country": "Ubited Kingdom",
  "Category": "BUS",
  "DateCreated": "2002:06:20",
  "GPSLatitude": "54 deg 59' 22.80\" N",
  "GPSLongitude": "1 deg 54' 51.00\" W",
  "GPSPosition": "54 deg 59' 22.80\" N, 1 deg 54' 51.00\" W",
  "ImageSize": "600x400",
}]
```

This is my html, what am I doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp" type="text/javascript">  </script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8)
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    $.getJSON('out1.json', function(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.Latlng(data[i].GPSLatitude, data[i].GPSLongtitude);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data[i].FileName
            });
        }
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: var map;
function initialize(){
//remove "var map = " replace to  "map = ..."
}

Comment: @HoangHieu still doesn't load..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/

post your code example to here :)

Comment: What does your JSON look like?  (a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful or even a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem)

Comment: @geocodezip I have edited my question, which includes my json file. Could it be that the format of GPSLatitude and GPSLongtitude is different inside the file, that's why nothing happened?

Answer (score 0):

if your Json data is true with your code get data :).

```
//with for(var i in data) // i.GPSLatitude;
//with for(var i =0; i< data.length; i++)  // data[i].GPSLatitude;
```

change

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp" type="text/javascript">  </script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var map;
var markers = new array();
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8)
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    $.getJSON('out.json', function(data) {

        for (var i =0; i< data.length; i++) {
//with for(var i in data) // i.GPSLatitude;
//with for(var i =0; i< data.length; i++)  // data[i].GPSLatitude;
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.Latlng(data[i].GPSLatitude, data[i].GPSLongtitude);

        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data[i].FileName
            });
        }
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It still can't work. Is it because in the JSON file, GPSLatitude and GPSLongtitude is in this format? 
"GPSLatitude": "33 deg 51' 21.91\" S",
"GPSLongitude": "151 deg 13' 11.73\" E",